# How do I make one filter take into consideration the order of other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I'm using the Filter (the one you create with the button in 'menus') to sort my table, but when I click the filter icon in a column's header and select "Sort A→Z", it only applies to that column.

[image]

**Current behavior**: As you can see, Column 1 is sorted from A→Z, while column 2 goes "ABACA" - it's not being sorted.

**Intended behavior**: Column 1 is sorted from A→Z, while columns 2-6 are also sorted from A→Z.
Basically, can I sort all of these columns from A→Z, with an interactable header button like the filter one? I'm pretty sure Excel can do something similar (while also letting you sort the individual columns), although I've never used the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard behaviour and can not be changed. If you want to sort multi-column range at once where sorting is not performed per single column but rather per whole rows in a given range, you are supposed to select a range you wish to sort and  choose from here:

[image: 0]

Comment: But that way someone viewing the sheet can't change the sorting. It's not interactable.
Is there no way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately no. this is the only way.